# Create a procedure in SQL Server, which confirm if the user insert the collect password and username

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

This what I have come up with:

```
Create table Users 
(
    UserName varchar(35) not null,
    Password varchar(35) not null,
    UserId int Foreign key references UserDetails (UserId)
)
```

This the procedure to confirm the username and password if it's correct:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Login
     @Username varchar(35),
     @Password varchar(35)
AS
BEGIN
     SELECT @Username = Username 
     FROM Users
     WHERE Username = @Username;

     SELECT @Password = Password
     FROM Users
     WHERE Password = @Password;
```

Comment: Side note: [CREATE PROCEDURE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures."

Comment: why you are taking separate statements when the both the columns belong to same table

Comment: Whats is your objectives?

Comment: Also: please ***DO NEVER EVER*** store your passwords in ***CLEAR TEXT!*** Passwords should always be salted + hashed for being stored!

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing your procedure name. `sp_` prefix is for built-in procedures.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  sp_Login
@Username varchar(35),
@Password varchar(35)

AS
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 
              FROM Users 
              WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@Password)
        SELECT 'SUCCESS' AS RESULT
    ELSE
        SELECT 'FAILURE' AS RESULT

END
```

Comment: mark it as answer if this answers your question. It will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[sp_Login]', N'P') IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].    [sp_Login] 
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Login]   
 @Username varchar(35),     
 @Password varchar(35),     
 @Userid int 
AS

IF EXISTS (SELECT 'exists' from Users where UserName = @Username AND Password = @Password AND UserId <> @Userid) 

BEGIN   
 RETURN TRUE; 
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN   
 RETURN FALSE; 
END
```